# C# equivalent of SysCommand and Call

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm converting some *old* VB.net to C#. Part of the code fires up a 3rd party console program and then sends it commands, like this:

```
Private APL As Object
Dim APLType As Type = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("APLW.WSEngine")
APL = Activator.CreateInstance(APLType)
APL.SysCommand("load " & APLLoc & APLFileName)
```

When converted, I ended up with this very similar code:

```
private object APL;
Type APLType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("APLW.WSEngine");
APL = Activator.CreateInstance(APLType);
APL.SysCommand("load " + APLLoc + APLFileName);
```

Unfortunately, .SysCommand is not present in C#. A later bit of code does:

```
Ans = APL.call("SFFile", ArgA);
```

Which also doesn't exist. Having never used any of these calls before, none of them known to VS2013 in either C# or VS (interesting?), and Google failing to find any trace of them (SysCommand turns up nothing, call gets 70 million bad hits), does anyone know the C# equivalent of this code?

No, I cannot import VisualBasic, this is ultimately a .Net Core project.

Comment: Declare `APL` as `dynamic`, i.e. `private dynamic APL;`

Comment: These are methods of whatever that type is (APLW.WSEngine).

Comment: SysCommand / Call are implemented in/by whatever the COM server "APLW.WSEngine" is ...

Comment: Ahhh, ok thanks guys. The trick was `dynamic`, which I have not used before.